# How can I backup and restore AppCenter apps between releases?

Tags: updates, appcenter, flatpak

I'm upgrading to the next release of Elementary OS and want an easy way to restore all the applications I have installed. While there is a provision for restoring AppCenter purchases [documented here](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/wiki/Saving-and-Restoring-Purchases), I did not find anything in the [Elementary release upgrade guide](https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/Release-Upgrades) dealing with free apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan M. in the Elementary OS slack community suggested using the 'flatpak list' console command, great idea.

I searched online and found [this technique](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/u3wcm7/easy_flatpak_apps_backupinstallation/?rdt=59985):

1 - Backup all your flatpak apps:

flatpak list --columns=application --app > flatpaks.txt
Here you are saving all your installed apps to a text file, without the dependencies/runtimes (they are downloaded automatically anyways).

2 - Install your apps in the new machine/installation:

xargs flatpak install -y < flatpaks.txt

Darshak P. from the slack also informs that "in case you have a separate /home partition, just reusing it in the new installation will keep all user flatpaks intact without you having to do anything."